# How to create a numerically "equal" function?

Tags: functions

A simple example about what I need to do. For example, I have three functions:

```
t1[x,t]
t2[x,t]
t3[x,t]
```

and,

```
t3[x_,t_]:=t1[x,t]+t2[x,t]
```

What is the best way to create a function t4[x,t] that is numerically "equal" to t3[x,t] but is not function of t1[x,t] and t2[x,t] in order to avoid a circular reference in a While loop program?

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t4[x_,t_]:=Evaluate[t1[x,t]+t2[x,t]]
```

Comment: Or equivalently just use `Set` ( = ) rather than `SetDelayed` ( := ) in the definition of t3.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting... if for example t1[x,t] is a interpolation function (came from NDSolve), I have to declare t4[x_?NumericQ,t_?NumericQ]:=Evaluate[t1[x,t]+t2[x,t]]. Still testing...